# android pay testing outside of US

Tags: braintree, android-pay

I am trying to integrate Android pay into my app using Braintree SDK.
To test this, we need "Android pay" app installed and we should add card details also right? I am using sandbox for testing..For testing on sandbox, do we need to add card(debit/credit) details into Android pay app? If so can I add test cards supported by Braintree? please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

For testing in sandbox you will need to add a real, valid card into the Android Pay app. Android Pay will not accept Braintree test cards.

Comment: So where all these money dedected from our cards will go?

Comment: The sandbox will not actually charge your card. The card is only used to demonstrate the app's flow; it will not be passed to Braintree at all. Fake information will be inserted instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick correct Android Pay apk variant from apkmirror website.
2. Turn on Sandbox Mode using

   adb shell
   cd /sdcard/Download;
   rm ­f android_pay_env_override_*;
   touch android_pay_env_override_sandbox;

For more detail
checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694039/how-to-test-android-pay-app-in-india)