# How to test android pay App in India

Tags: java, android, android-pay

We are trying to integrate android pay functionality into our android application using below tutorial link:
 https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial

To test this, we need "Android pay" app installed on device,so we have downloaded and installed it from given link: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-pay/android-pay-1-2-111627672-release/#downloads

After that we have tried to add card details to "Android Pay" app but got "Your card can't added at this time.Please try again later" message.

Let we know any way to add card details on Android Pay application outside US user,so we can test the Android pay functionality in our application.

Comment: I don't think India is the problem. do you have a developer account? its free (in the testing stage) http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html

Comment: I do have android developer account.Let me know the steps to use developer account  in Android Pay app for testing purpose

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJ4lz2z6cAA this is an older video. Google api really expands the android device capabilities https://console.developers.google.com billing is one of the features but also maps, social media, google play etc developer.android.com the  official site click "developer console" Google of course owns android. Development is free but production cost a lot well worth it though as the google play app is where almost everyone downloads their apps. Google play app ships with the phone check it out and get back with me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435256/access-to-google-play-android-developer-api you can find many answers here on stackoverflow about google play api also developer.google.com

Comment: the link you gave step 1 talks about setting up your google account on the google developer console. If you want google to do the billing for you it has a link to how to do that. Its a good idea to have google do your billing unless you really have large amounts of money to design your own billing system and you own your own bank and a team of accountants and IT staff

Answer (score 4):

Perform following steps by connecting your phone, to convert Android pay into testable environment:

1. Install Android Pay apk from apkmirror website. Make sure you use correct apk variant.
2. Turn on Sandbox Mode by executing following commands from command prompt:

`adb shell
cd /sdcard/Download;
rm ­f android_pay_env_override_*;
touch android_pay_env_override_sandbox;`

3. Reboot the phone
4. Launch the Android Pay app and add following test credit card:
   `Card Number: 4622 9431 2999 9943`
   `Expiry: 12/17` `CVV: 125`
5. Enter other details like address and proceed. So that card is added successfully.

You're done. Use ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to integrate and test Android Pay in your app.

Happy Testing !

PS: Revert from Sandbox to Production - Developer Instructions:

1. Run following commands to revert Android Pay from Sandbox environment to Production environment:

`adb shell
cd /sdcard/Download;
rm ­f android_pay_env_override_*;`

2. Restart your phone
3. Use ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION or ENVIRONMENT_TEST to integrate and test Android Pay in your app

Comment: Had all sandbox setup and successfully added card. But we are getting error code 8 from Full Wallet Request. So, i am not identifying the exact problem. Can you please suggest something.

Comment: Have tried this several times but keep getting "Your card couldn't be added".  Is this working for other people?

Comment: Can we add address of india?

Answer (score 0):

There is test environment in Android Pay "API"

But no test environment for Android Pay "APP"

You must add a "real" credit card which issued by banks in US to Android Pay APP. And Android Pay not support all US banks, you can find supported banks list here:https://support.google.com/androidpay/answer/6314169?hl=en

You can start test after add a real card in Android Pay APP even outside US.

Comment: I don't have a 'real' credit card. The client is not willing to share his card details as he feels I can misuse it.

Comment: Doesn't Google provide any test card numbers(to add it on Android Pay application) for developers to test the API ?

Comment: I think not. I can't find any in Android Pay documents. Or you can suggest your client provide a debit card.