# Android Pay integration in india

Tags: android, android-pay

Android pay doesn't allow to add an Indian card and due to that I'm unable to test my app in India. I've seen [How to test android pay App in India](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694039/how-to-test-android-pay-app-in-india), but in test environment it doesn't allow me to add the given card details and I read that you have to add a working card but it won't deduct money from that in test mode, for that I tried my working Indian bank card but even that doesn't help.

Please someone guide me how to handle this in India.

Comment: Your indian card might not be Credit Card Requires credit card

Comment: Since Android Pay hasn't launched in India, you can't test with a real card there. You can only use test mode.